# How to de (serialize) _links so that value of "rel" value appear as element and _link as nested json

Tags: json, jackson, spring-hateoas

Spring hatios latest is keeping links as array rather than nested json and keeping relation name as "rel". We want "rel" value as child jsons root name. Please see the current and expected behaviour.

CURRENT BEHAVIOUR:

```
  [
    {
        "id": "id-1",
        "name": "abc",
        "description": "abc",
        "enrollments": [
            {
                "links": [
                    {
                        "rel": "fees",
                        "id": "feesId-1",
                        "href": "xyz"
                    },
                    {
                        "rel": "rates",
                        "id": "ratesId-1",
                        "href": "abc"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

EXPECTED:

```
[
    {
      "id": "id-1",
      "name": "abc",
      "description": "abc",
      "enrollments": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "end_timestamp": "2025-12-31T16:06:05Z",
          "_links": {
            "rates": {
              "id": "ratesId-1",
              "href": "abc"
            },
            "fees": {
              "id": "feesId-1",
              "href": "xyz"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning [CollectionModel](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/CollectionModel.html) instead of List resoloved the issue in my case.